# pandas value_counts( ) not in descending order

Tags: python, pandas

There is a dataframe,df

```
Index              Date               Name         Category
 0            2017-08-09              ABC-SAP       1
 1            2017-08-09              CDE-WAS       2
 2            2017-08-10              DEF           3
 3            2017-08-11              DEF           3
 4            2017-08-11              CDE-WAS       2
 5            2017-08-11              CDE-WAS       2
```

I executed this code:

```
df2=pd.DataFrame(df, columns= ['Name','Category'])
df2= df['Name'].groupby(df['Category']).value_counts()
print(df2)
```

Then I get:

```
 Index             Name
 (1,ABC-SAP)       1              
 (2,CDE-WAS)       3                         
 (3,DEF)           2
```

The value.counts( ) does not return a descending order on the NAME column. I really want to have it in descending order from highest to lowest count. Any way of doing it?

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me it working nice, but you can test alternative solution:

```
df2 = df['Name'].groupby(df['Category']).value_counts()
print(df2)
Category  Name   
Pri       CDE-WAS    3
          DEF        2
          ABC-SAP    1
Name: Name, dtype: int64


df2 = df.groupby('Category')['Name'].value_counts()
print(df2)
Category  Name   
Pri       CDE-WAS    3
          DEF        2
          ABC-SAP    1
Name: Name, dtype: int64
```

EDIT:

For sort all values use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('Category')['Name'].value_counts().sort_values(as‌​cending=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but It didn't work. It seems to be ordered by the alphabetic ordering of the index and not by the count of occurrences. my pandas version is v3.6

Comment: it is python version, what about `print (pd.show_versions())` ?

Comment: pandas: 0.20.3. I have edited the question. The category column has numeric values but I replaced it with the words(Pri) before and it is still giving the unordered result

Comment: OK, are data confidental?

Comment: OK, if use some another data like `df = pd.DataFrame({'Category':[5,5,5,9,1,1,1,5,1,1],
                   'Name':list('aaabbaabba')})
` it failed too?

Comment: I have idea, is possible upgrade pandas?

Comment: [Category  Name
    1         a       3
               b       2
    5         a       3
               b       1
    9         b       1
  Name: Name, dtype: int64
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x1f9b0ad8390>]

Comment: because `value_count` function with groupby count each category.

Comment: what I really expect is to order by the count  from highest to lowest irrespective of the category

Comment: So do you need `df1 = df.groupby('Category')['Name'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False)` ?

Comment: Could you help out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47933691/grouping-by-day-of-the-week-pandas

Comment: Please fix the `df1 = df.groupby('Category')['Name'].value_counts().sort_values(as‌​cending=False)` example. It contains invisible encoded characters. *I cannot edit because the modification is less than 6 characters.*